# How to make offline installation of node-inspector?

Tags: node.js, github, npm, windows-server-2012, node-inspector

How to offline install node-inspector on Windows server? 
The code is here: https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-inspector

Answer (score 1):

To my best knowledge, it's not possible to install Node Inspector (or any npmjs package) directly from npmjs.org and/or github.com without a working internet connection. However, you can prepare a self-containing package on a machine that does have internet connection, and then install this package on an offline host.

Here are the instructions, assuming Unix system.

1. On the machine connected to the internet

   ```
   $ mkdir tempdir && cd tempdir
   $ npm init # fill any data to prompts
   $ npm install node-inspector
   $ cd node_modules/node-inspector
   $ tar czf ../../node-inspector.tgz .
   $ cd ../..
   ```
2. Copy `node-inspector.tgz` to the offline machine and unpack it in the directory of your choice, e.g. `$HOME/node-inspector` or `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-inspector`
3. Create symlinks for `node-inspector` and `node-debug` in a folder that is in your `PATH`. For example:

   ```
   $ cd /usr/local/bin
   $ ln -s ../lib/node_modules/node-inspector/bin/node-inspector .
   $ ln -s ../lib/node_modules/node-inspector/bin/node-debug .
   ```

Comment: Great, but in Windows?? How we can do It?

Comment: That's more tricky. You can use "npm pack" and "npm install" instead of tar. In order to bundle all Node Inspector dependencies in the archive, you need to edit package.json and list all dependencies as bundled. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/bundle-deps and https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bundleddependencies